# Jquery detect click OR keystroke?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to combine these two into one to avoid duplicated the code twice:

```
document.querySelector('body').onkeydown = function(e){
  if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 77) {
    e.preventDefault();
     // code...
    }
}

$("button").on('click', function(){
     // code...
});
```

Basically I want to be able to either click on the element or press a key.

Comment: Call a function? That's what they are for.

Comment: They already are functions aren't they?

Comment: @Hasen Yes, but they are *separate* functions right now, each defined inside a different event handler. You can combine the code to execute into a single function, then call it from either event listener.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @forgivenson suggested, you can avoid code duplication by putting your executable code into a **[function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)**. It would look like this:

```
document.querySelector('body').onkeydown = function(e){
  if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 77) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doSomething(); // call your function on keydown
  }
}

$("button").on('click', doSomething); // call your function on click

function doSomething() {
  // code to execute on keydown or click
}
```

Below is an example. Typing `m` (or `M`) or clicking the button will call your code.

```js
$("input").on('keydown', function(e){
  if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 77) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doSomething(); // call your function on keydown
  }
});

$("button").on('click', doSomething); // call your function on click

function doSomething() {
  // code to execute on keydown or click
  console.log("You typed 'm' or clicked the button.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Type here">
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about calling a function ???

```
function doStuff(){

}


document.querySelector('body').onkeydown = function(e){
  if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 77) {
    e.preventDefault();
     doStuff()
    }
}

$("button").on('click', doStuff);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put all your code in a function, `someFunc` then you can call it

```js
function someFunc() {
  alert('Hi');
}

document.querySelector('body').onkeydown = function(e){
  if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 77) {
    e.preventDefault();
      someFunc();
    }
}

$("button").on('click', function(){
     someFunc();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button>Click me or `m` in your keyboard</button>
```